# D3 update data, number rows in html table, animate svgs in last column

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to update data in an HTML table with D3. I need to change the data in multiple columns, update the number of rows, and animate an SVG in each row according to each new data array. I have tried multiple attempts, tutorials, documentation, and I'm certain this is an easy one for someone more experienced with the library.

One method I have commented in the code `tbody.selectAll('tr').remove();` just wipes the table clean of all rows. But then it's impossible to animate the SVG because there is no starting position.

The current method I have is also wrong, though I'm new to D3 so I'm not sure why. When new data comes in it doesn't replace the old data properly but affects the row length based on the new length, sometimes replacing, but usually appending. Click "run" on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ow3n/9vvdyp57/) until you see the id appear with a lower number (e.g. "7"). Then press the update button and you'll see the new data doesn't update the rows, but appends to them based on the number in the new array. So if the next array happens to have 8 then you'll see one 8. And if the following has 10 then you'll see two tens. I'm certain once this is fixed it will also fix the SVG animation.

[image: screenshot of table with three "updates"]

Here is the generic code I am working with.

```
// create table, etc.
var table = d3.select('.chart').append('table');
var thead = table.append('thead');
var tbody = table.append('tbody');

// append the header row
thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(['id','val','svg']).enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function (col_names) { return col_names; });

function update_table(){

  data = newdata(); // update data to display

  // remove existing rows
  // this basically resets the table element
  // but is not the right way
  //tbody.selectAll('tr').remove();

  // join new data with old elements, if any
  var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

  // add first two columns
  rows.append('td').text(function(d) { return d.id; })
  rows.append('td').text(function(d) { return d.val; });  

  // add svg
  var svgcell = rows.append('td')
    .append('svg')
      .attr("width",20)
      .attr("height",20);  
  svgcell.append('circle').transition().duration(500)
    .attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.val; })
    .style("fill", "red");

   tbody.selectAll('tr').data(data).exit().remove();  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is a little bit unusual for a D3 code: you want to update the rows according to the data, but you don't want to remove the `<td>`s containing the circles... that rules out the simplest solution, which is defining the [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data) for the data binding function based on the value column:

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.val
    });
```

With that easy fix out of the table, my solution here is a little awkward.

First, set the update selection:

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data);
```

And then the enter selection:

```
var rowsEnter = rows.enter()
    .append('tr');

rowsEnter.append('td')
    .attr("class", "idColumn")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });
rowsEnter.append('td')
    .attr("class", "valColumn")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.val;
    });

rowsEnter.append('td')
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20).append('circle')
    .attr("class", "svgCircle")
    .style("fill", "red");
```

Now, select all columns by class, rebind the data (that's the awkward part I mentioned before), and set the transition for the circles:

```
d3.selectAll(".idColumn").data(data).text(function(d) {
    return d.id;
});
d3.selectAll(".valColumn").data(data).text(function(d) {
    return d.val;
});
d3.selectAll(".svgCircle").data(data).attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("cy", 10).transition().duration(500)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.val;
    })
    .style("fill", "red");
```

Finally, the exit selection:

```
rows.exit().remove();
```

And here is the demo:

```js
// D3 update data, number rows in html table, animate svgs in last column
function newdata() {
    var n = [];
    var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20);
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        n.push({
            "id": r,
            "val": Math.random() * 10
        });
    }
    return n;
}
var data = newdata(); // generate data array of random length

// create table, etc.
var table = d3.select('.chart').append('table');
var thead = table.append('thead');
var tbody = table.append('tbody');

// append the header row
thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(['id', 'val', 'svg']).enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function(col_names) {
        return col_names;
    });

// update function
function update_table() {
    // update data to display
    data = newdata();

    // remove existing rows
    // this basically resets the table element
    // but is not the right way
    //tbody.selectAll('tr').remove();

    // join new data with old elements, if any
    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data);

    var rowsEnter = rows.enter()
        .append('tr');

    rowsEnter.append('td')
        .attr("class", "idColumn")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.id;
        });
    rowsEnter.append('td')
        .attr("class", "valColumn")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.val;
        });

    rowsEnter.append('td')
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20).append('circle')
        .attr("class", "svgCircle")
        .style("fill", "red");

    d3.selectAll(".idColumn").data(data).text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });
    d3.selectAll(".valColumn").data(data).text(function(d) {
        return d.val;
    });
    d3.selectAll(".svgCircle").data(data).attr("cx", 10)
        .attr("cy", 10).transition().duration(500)
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d.val;
        })
        .style("fill", "red");

    rows.exit().remove();

}
update_table();

var button = document.getElementById("update");
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    update_table();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button id="update">update</button>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

If you prefer a fiddle, here is it: https://jsfiddle.net/evzx2x6L/

Comment: Gerardo this is great. So it appears I had two issues: 1) I needed to select rows.enter() not rows? and 2) because of the hierarchical issue of the html table structure and my need for the data to change the number of rows(?) I needed an alternate way to select/enter the SVG into the last cell?

Comment: 1) Yes, you need to have a separate "enter" and "update" selection. Actually, you should use only an "enter" and an "exit" selection here, since you'll never (probably) get the same random number twice. However, due to the SVG problem, we had to set a "fake" update selection, which leads us to number 2: 2) Yes, because you didn't want to remove the last cell (the SVG one), we need that "unusual" code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the right way to do this but I animated the svgs with D3 by applying the transform property 1 second after the update function is called and it works.

```js
// D3 update data, number rows in html table, animate svgs in last column

function newdata(){
  var n = [];
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  for (var i=0; i<r; i++){
    n.push({ "id": i, "val": Math.random() * 10 });
  }
  return n;
} 
var data = newdata(); // generate data array of random length

// create table, etc.
var table = d3.select('.chart').append('table');
var thead = table.append('thead');
var tbody = table.append('tbody');

// append the header row
thead.append('tr')
 .selectAll('th')
 .data(['id','val','svg']).enter()
 .append('th')
 .text(function (col_names) { return col_names; });

// update function
function update_table(){
 // update data to display
  data = newdata();
  
  // remove existing rows
  // this basically resets the table element
  // but is not the right way
  tbody.selectAll('tr').remove();
  
  // join new data with old elements, if any
  var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('tr');

 // add first two columns
  rows.append('td').text(function(d) { return d.id; })
  rows.append('td').text(function(d) { return d.val; });  
  
  // add svg
  var svgcell = rows.append('td')
    .append('svg')
      .attr("width",20)
      .attr("height",20);  
  svgcell.append('circle')
  .attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.val; })
    .style("fill", "red");
    
   tbody.selectAll('tr').data(data).exit().remove(); 

}
update_table();


var button = document.getElementById("update");
button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    update_table();
  setTimeout(function(){
   document.querySelectorAll("circle").forEach(function(e){
         d3.select(e)
            .attr("transform", "scale(0)")
            .transition()
            .duration(400)
            .attr("transform", "scale(1)")
        }); 
},10);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="update">update</button>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

Comment: This is one way, but it only affects the SVGs. The bigger issue is still there; the new data doesn't replace the old data properly but affects the row length based on the new length, sometimes replacing, but usually appending. "Run" the jsfiddle enough until you see the id appear with a lower number then press the update button and you'll see it. Once this is fixed then the transition to the SVGs should be correct because it will start from the preceding value. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: So you wanted to remove the elements on the table and animate after the new elements are added? If that's so the new edit I've made must have answered your question.

Comment: Thanks again. But as I pointed out in the code ```tbody.selectAll('tr').remove();``` deletes all the table rows, and is not the correct way to do it. While the rows refresh, the SVGs also do so, and animate from ```0,0``` not from their previous state.